# Objective C array = new double[ ]; behavior in Java

Tags: java, objective-c, arrays

Im rewriting part of one algorithm from Objective C source code into my java program and dont know whether im doing it right (probably not). The problem is, there is an array thats being passed into other functions and its size and values may vary on the fly.

Objective C main:

```
 double[] output = new double[1]; 
 foo(output);
```

and function:

```
public void Run(out double[] output){

  /* Dimensioning the array, i dont understand this part, why is it 
  being allocated again? 
  Is it to increase the size in case the number is bigger than outputs 
  current dimension and does it keep values in the old part of the array? */
  output = new double[number];


  // Copy new values to the output array
  for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
  output[i] = i+number;
  }
  //Now i should be able to access these new values in main
}
```

I replaced my array in java code with `ArrayList<Double> output` and had to make significant changes to other functions because of it. I know Java passes only by value but is there some trick or some other way to make changes to the output array so it behaves like in Objective C? I have never programmed in Objective C before. How does the allocation part above work in Objective C?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes java is pass by value by default mostly in primitive but it is pass by reference when it is an object.

here is an example of pass by reference through object using `ArrayList` of `Integer`.

```
public static void run(ArrayList<Integer> a)
{
    int n = 10;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a.add(i+n); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    run(b); 

    for(Integer in : b)
        System.out.println(in);
}
```

Comment: Everything is pass by value in BOTH languages.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what i used but does it work the same way as the Objective C code? I mean they are allocating new array into the output array and im not sure if my usage of  output.clear(); does the same effect.

Comment: @CrimsonChris yes java by default is pass by value. but values of object are pass by reference

Comment: @GiomePoolGuy when add is call it is allocating new memory to the heap and add it to the arraylist.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin You are mistaken. Java is always pass by value. The same is true of objective-c. There are many questions on this very site that agree. Read this... http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Comment: @CrimsonChris and how are you gonna explain the code in my post?. It is clearly pass by reference on values of ArrayList

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin No, you are passing a pointer to your array list by value. There's a difference. Read the article.

Comment: Java is always pass by value. You're misunderstanding what the value is here. It's not the object. It's the object reference.

Answer (score 1):

Your "Objective-C" array above uses the *new* operator which means it's probably actually C++ code from an Objective-C++ program.  Also there's a function call in there, instead of sending a message to an object, so that's another clue that's actually a bit of C++ code.  I don't see any pointers, so it looks like it's allocated on the stack.  It's also not resizable, it will always hold only 1 element, which is silly.  In summary: I think you're a bit confused about the original code.

Comment: Hmm, that baffles me. No idea why would they want it to be array for 1 element only though.